# Let $ U=\operatorname{Ker}(T-I)$, $ W=\operatorname{Ker}(T+I) $ be two subspaces of $V$. Show that $V=U \oplus W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T \in \mathscr{L}(V, V)$ be such that $T^2=I$. Let
$$
U=\operatorname{Ker}(T-I), \quad W=\operatorname{Ker}(T+I)
$$
be two subspaces of $V$. Show that $V=U \oplus W$.

I proved it in this way: $(T-I)(T+I)=O, (T+I)(T-I)=O$, so that $U=Ker(T-I)=T+I$, $W=Ker(T+I)=T-I$.
$T^2=I$, $\therefore T$ is invertible. $dimT=dimV$, so that $T=V$
$U+W=2T$,  $\therefore U+W=V$.
If $\mathbf{v}\in Ker U$, then $(T+I)\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}=T\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{v}$
thus $T\mathbf{v}=-\mathbf{v}$, then $W\mathbf{v}=(T-I)\mathbf{v}=-2\mathbf{v}$,
only when $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$, $KerW=KerU$,
thus $U\cap W=\{\mathbf{0}\}$,
Therefore, we can conclude that $V=U\oplus W$.

But by checking the answer I found that I can simply write U as $U=\{ \mathbf{u}\in V,T(\mathbf{u})=\mathbf{u} \}$, and the same for W. But it seems that it's contradicted to my proof? Anyone know why?

Comment: Here you write $\operatorname{Ker}(T-I)=T+I$. How can this be understood?

Comment: Is $V$ a real vector space (or at least is over a ground field $k$ with $\operatorname{char} k\not = 2$?)

Comment: I think I made a mistake here, it should be $\subset$ but not "=". May be I can use "=" only after proving $Ker(T+I)=Ker(T-I)$? @kabenyuk

Comment: V is a real vector space (I forgot to mention)@anomaly

Answer (score 2):

Consider $v\in V$ arbitrary. Note that we can write
$$v=\frac{T+I}{2}v-\frac{T-I}{2}v.$$
Note that $(T+I)(T-I)=0=(T-I)(T+I)$, because $T^2=I$. Thus, we can conclude that
$$\frac{T+I}{2}v\in\ker(T-I) \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ -\frac{T-I}{2}v\in\ker(T+I).$$
Therefore, $V=\ker(T-I)+\ker(T+I)$.

Now, suppose $x\in\ker(T-I)\cap\ker(T+I)$. Then $(T-I)x=0$ and $(T+I)x=0$. This implies that $T(x)=x$ and $T(x)=-x$. Thus, we have $2x=0$, which implies $x=0$.

Therefore, $\ker(T-I)\cap\ker(T+I)=\{0\}$.

Since $V=\ker(T-I)+\ker(T+I)$ and $\ker(T-I)\cap\ker(T+I)=\{0\}$, we can conclude that
$$V=\ker(T-I)\oplus\ker(T+I).$$

Comment: I get it now. Thank you!